# Select <a> with Jquery... headache since 2 hours

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-lists, traversal

through a list, this is my html code:

```
<ul class="choix-kit_modele_list">
        <li class="first modele"><a href="">Modèle :</a></li>
        <li><a href="">A1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">A3</a>
            <ul class="choix-kit_type_list">
                <li class="first type"><a href="">Type :</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3 Portes - 1999 à 2003</a></li>
                <li><a href="">3 Portes - 2004 à Aujourd'hui</a></li>
                <li><a href="">5 Portes - 1999 à 2003</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Cabriolet - 2008 à Aujourd'hui</a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="">Sportback - 2005 à Aujourd'hui</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="last"><a href="">A4 Berline</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I would like to select only  of the first level of the list, so this is my code, wich select all :

```
$('.choix-kit_modele_list li > a').not('.choix-kit_type_list li a').each(function(i){
   $(this).css({width: 100});
});
```

So i said that "select me a of the first ul but not his ul child, via calling them by their respective class. So what's wrong in my code please ?

Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: thanks, can you explain with more details how does your code works, and why my code is wrong ? thanks again

Comment: You might want to accept an answer - It's a good way to ensure people will want to answer your questions in the future too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child selector should be between `.choix-kit_modele_list` and `li`, because every `a` is a child of `li` on all levels:

```
$('.choix-kit_modele_list > li a').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({ width: 100 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$('.choix-kit_modele_list li > a').not('.choix-kit_type_list li a')
```

to:

```
$('.choix-kit_modele_list > li > a')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul.choix-kit_modele_list > li > a').each(function(){
   $(this).css("font-size", "26px");
});
```

Your code wasn't working, because your selector applied to every link that is a direct descendant of every `<li>` that's a descendant of your first ul - direct or not - in your HTML.

Adding > before the li part in the selector makes sure that you only operate on `<li>`-items that are direct descendants of your ul, thus stopping it from entering the second ul.

Hope that clears it up.